# How to trigger an event without clicking the button in javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to  write a code to trigger an event in  pure javascript without clicking the button.

i would like the solution to be more generic so that it can be apllied to any event. Like if i want to trigger either button click or drop down etc without actual mouse or keyboard activity.

we have seething for submit button without clicking on it--document.formid.submit();

Comment: You can either use the jQuery `trigger` method, or natively https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Comment: you just need to create a javascript function and bind it with whaever action you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to trigger event in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

jQuery's `trigger` method can be used to trigger an event:

https://jsfiddle.net/gRoberts/4xah6nph/

```
$('#test').click(function(e) {
    alert('jQuery: You clicked me!');
});

setTimeout(function() {
    $('#test').trigger('click');
}, 5000);
```

or alternatively you can use

```
var elem = document.getElementById('test');
elem.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    alert('Navtive: You clicked me!');
});
setTimeout(function() {
    elem.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
}, 6000);
```